# How to use the --query and --filters with aws rds describe-db-instances to retrieve the OptionGroupName value of an RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-cli

I would like to retrieve the DB Option Group (OptionGroupName) for an RDS by using the `aws rds describe-db-instances --query` and `--filters`.

Just FYI I can not use `jq` to filter the json response from `aws rds describe-db-instances`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Output of `describe-db-instances` looks something like:

```json
{
    "DBInstances": [
        {
            "PubliclyAccessible": true, 
            "MasterUsername": "bos", 
            "OptionGroupMemberships": [
                {
                    "Status": "in-sync", 
                    "OptionGroupName": "default:postgres-9-6"
                }
            ], 
            ...
```

The `OptionGroupMemberships` element is a *list*, so it might contain multiple values. If you are only seeking the value of the first item in the list, you would use:

```
--query 'DBInstances[*].OptionGroupMemberships[0].OptionGroupName'
```

You can combine it with other elements like this:

```
--query 'DBInstances[*].[MasterUsername,OptionGroupMemberships[0].OptionGroupName]'
```

You can also append `--output text` to obtain the value without JSON formatting.

If I ever need to experiment with the `--query` values, I go to [JMESPath Tutorial — JMESPath](https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html) and paste my JSON into the examples. I can then interactively attempt to write the correct query (which is how I derived the above answers).

Answer (score 0):

I just found my answer

```
aws rds describe-db-instances --db-instance-identifier <My_RDS_IDENTIFIER> --query 'DBInstances[*].[OptionGroupMemberships]'
```

Comment: I try to retrieve only the OptionGroupName from the above request but I don't know how to filter on this value. Any suggestion ?
I tried with --query 'DBInstances[*].[OptionGroupMemberships].[OptionGroupName]' and tried with --query 'DBInstances[*].[OptionGroupMemberships].[OptionGroupName]..[OptionGroupName]' and tried with .[OptionGroupName].[0] but it doesn't works as expected